# How to use webpack2 for html and css compressor

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am using webpack2 with babel-loader to convert ES6 to ES5, and we plan to use html and css loader with webpack, how to start and implementation?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty similar to Webpack 1, here is an upgrade guide: https://webpack.js.org/how-to/upgrade-from-webpack-1/

You can check my working TodoMVC implementation if you don't want to find out everything yourself: https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-todomvc/

Comment: Thank you! It really helps.